# How to add second texture uniform in Kick.js shader editor

Tags: glsl, webgl

How do I add a 2nd texture uniform in the Kick.js shader editor so my shader can use it? The URL for Kick.js is:
http://www.kickjs.org/example/shader_editor/shader_editor.html

I modified the default shader in Kick.js. It uses one texture. I successfully used the 'Textures' panel to add a 2nd texture by referencing an image I found with images.google.com.

Now the problem is that the 'Uniforms' panel does not show the texture sampler uniform. How can I make this uniform appear?

By the way, here is my shader code. However, I do not believe this code is part of the problem. Thanks for any help.

```js
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif
varying vec3 vColor;
varying vec2 uv;

uniform sampler2D video_tex;
uniform sampler2D video_mask;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 samp_video = texture2D(video_tex,uv);
    vec4 samp_mask = texture2D(video_mask,uv);

    vec3 samp_virtual = vec3(1,0,0);

    float alpha = samp_mask.r;
    //gl_FragColor.rgb = (alpha)*samp_virtual.rgb + (1.0-alpha)*samp_video.rgb;
    gl_FragColor.rgb = samp_mask.rgb;  
    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works just fine :)

You need to bind the textures to the uniform variables. The process takes two steps:

1. Set the textures (in the Textures panel). [image]
2. Setup the uniforms to bind your uniform variables to the texture [image]

Comment: My problem is that I do not see the list of Uniforms as you have shown them here.

How can I make the video_tex uniform appear as you have shown?

I'm trying to post an image.
http://imageshack.us/a/img651/8592/kickjs.jpg

Comment: The GLSL compiler optimizes the samp_video and video_tex away since they are unused. If you modify your code to use the samp_video, the uniform will appear and you can bind the texture.